# strange implicit conversion of data type in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I create a simple numpy of data type uint as below:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.uint)
```

When I compute

```
a[0] + 1
```

I expect a result of 2, but it gives

```
2.0
```

Why there is such an implicit conversion to float for np.uint? Note that it does not happen with int or np.int64

Comment: Note, in general, the way promotion works with numpy scalars is [pretty arcane](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13591) and not well documented, I think. I believe there might recently have been an overhaul. EDIT: An [even more relevant github issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7126#issuecomment-175571231)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to track down this closely related [github issue on the numpy repo](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7126). [According to Robert Kern](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7126#issuecomment-175571231), a major contributor to `numpy` and `scipy`, the decision about the result type is made based on the input types. `numpy` relies on underlying routines that have type-specific implementations where both arguments are of the same type, so it has to promote to *some* common type. In this case, the issue is that one type is unsigned and the other is signed:

> ...it's a confluence of several factors. The implementation of the
> `numpy.add()` ufunc that underlies these routines only has type-specific
> implementations where the two arguments are of the same type. So the
> ufunc system needs to cast the arguments to a common type. One of the
> arguments is signed, so both arguments need to be casted to a signed
> type. The smallest signed type that can represent values up through
> the maximum range of `uint64` is `float64` (Note! Not all `uint64` values
> can be represented as `float64` floats! Precision is lost! But it's
> better than `int64` where the whole upper half of the values are lost.).

Note, a similar thing occurs with unsigned and signed numpy types,  `np.uint` and `np.int`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.uint(0) + np.int64(1)
1.0
```