# strange implicit conversion after append an empty list in numpy

Tags: numpy

After the thread [strange implicit conversion of data type in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69881602/strange-implicit-conversion-of-data-type-in-numpy), I found another strange conversion with numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=int)
c = np.append(a, [])
```

print the c gives:

```
array([1., 2., 3.])
```

However, if:

```
c = np.append(a, [4])
```

gives:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

why is there such strange automatic conversion? It does not make any sense at all

Comment: check the dtype of `np.array([])`  Also look at the [source] for `np.append`

Answer (score 0):

The empty list has to be first turned into an array:

```
In [149]: np.array([])
Out[149]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

`np.append` actually does:

```
In [151]: np.ravel([])
Out[151]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

The `append` code:

```
def append(arr, values, axis=None):
    arr = asanyarray(arr)
    if axis is None:
        if arr.ndim != 1:
            arr = arr.ravel()
        values = ravel(values)
        axis = arr.ndim-1
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
```